# No pdo drivers found

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to work on a sqlite3 database with php on windows10, but I get `could not find driver in ...`. When I run phpinfo, I get the line `PDO drivers =>` . But the lines `extension=pdo_sqlite`, `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll` and `extension=sqlite3` are uncommented and I have set the extension_dir to the absolute path to my ext folder. Anyone knows how to hep me ?

Comment: Did you restart your server after making changes to php.ini? Is it the correct php.ini you edited?

Comment: Yes, I restart the server after each changes on my php.ini. I don't know if I have modified the right php.ini

Comment: Your `phpinfo()` should tell you which one it is

Comment: ```phpinfo()``` says ```Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>```